# Condition on a cell that contains an IF stmt

Tags: excel, vba

I have cell A6 with a formula that looks for a content match of SS #'s in another cell B10 within a range of cells and displays the first record number if it there is a match:

```
=IF(MATCH($B$10,Curr_Cycle_SS_Nos,0)>0,"SS # matches record "&MATCH($B$10,Curr_Cycle_SS_Nos,0)&" in batch.","")
```

I cannot seem to create an IF...THEN statement in my macro that will match the TRUE state of the condition. E.g. I have tried using
If (Len("A6") > 0) Then...
Even though that expression will evaluate properly in a cell on the spreadsheet (without the " marks) it will not work in my macro.

I've tried many different tests besides the LEN function with different syntax but I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - question was originally about VBA, so:

`Len("A6")` is 2 because the string `"A6"` is 2 characters long.

`Len(Range("A6").Value2)` will measure the length of text in cell `A6` which looks like what you want to achieve.

---

If anyone is interested how to improve the formula from the question:

[`MATCH`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) function returns an integer if it finds something, but returns `#N/A!` error if it doesn't find any matching value.

[`IFERROR`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx) is a useful function to capture cases when a formula returns an error value. In your case, just use:

```
=IFERROR(
    "SS # matches record " & MATCH($B$10, Curr_Cycle_SS_Nos, 0) & " in batch.",
    "")
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not having trouble with that formula on the spreadsheet. That formula works fine. The problem is that I want to display a message box when I run the macro if the statement evaluates to TRUE. But as I said, everything works fine on the spreadsheet but I can't figure out how to do a proper evaluation in the macro.

Comment: @Rezenalize - ah, I updated your question tags that you are not interested in excel formula after all.

Comment: Wasn't my original tax Excel-VBA, not just Excel?

Comment: it was just excel by the time I saw it.

Comment: Thanks, someone else edited it to say excel. I hope I get an answer. I've struggled with this all day.

Comment: I updated my answer. There might be better solutions in terms of performance if A6 is not the only cell you need to measure, but at least it works.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much, Aprillon! I had used Range and .value but not together.